# Xcode showing duplicate project

Tags: ios, xcode, bitbucket

Never seen this before. Xcode is displaying duplicate project although only single exists on the disk. I have tried refreshing the status from Source control and also checked remote repository, only one exists there. When I refer both in Show in finder, both point to the same location. My worry is if the location is same, and I try to delete any of them, the project will be deleted.

[image]

Comment: clean the build(command + shift + K), build again, fore quit Xcode and restart you pc . I had a similar issue that was solved by this

Comment: Delete derive data -> clean -> build

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the project and the associated files without Xcode going mental, and without having to manually re-import all files to the project.